# Return error messages for sending emails

Tags: php, performance

How can I optimize this piece of code and avoid the multiple `if/else` call for returning error message ?

```
    if ($cardStatus == true) {

        $cardEmailContent = $this->setCardEmailContent();
        $sendUserEmail    = $this->sendCardToUser($cardEmailContent);

        if ($sendUserEmail) { 
            $this->sendAdminEmail();
            $this->updateCardDetails();
        } else {
            return $sendUserEmail;
        }

    } else {
        return $this->cardApiError;
    }
```

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Comment: There is not much context to this, and only a few lines of code to review. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By switching the `if` condition to check if `$cardStatus` is false and the same for `$sendUserEmail` you will reduce some of the nesting.

```
if (!$cardStatus) {
    return $this->cardApiError;
}

$cardEmailContent = $this->setCardEmailContent();
$sendUserEmail    = $this->sendCardToUser($cardEmailContent);

if (!$sendUserEmail) { 
    return $sendUserEmail;
}

$this->sendAdminEmail();
$this->updateCardDetails();
```

by using these guard clauses it avoids the upcoming arrow antipattern.

Answer (score 3):

### It's fine.

Your naming is quite good, and overall the code looks perfectly fine, at least to me. It's difficult to say much more without seeing what happens behind the scene, like `$this->sendCardToUser($cardEmailContent);`.

---

The only thing I noticed you could change, to make it shorter *(but not necessarily clearer)* is `if ($cardStatus == true)` could be just *`if ($cardStatus)`*.